# Popup color from color string like `#f2d3aa` with Emacs

Tags: emacs, colors

I'm using scss-mode in Emacs.

There are a lot of color string like `#f2d3aa` in text.

I wonder if there is a function that pop up a color square from string of current position.

Is there a emacs function like this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm using [`rainbow-mode`](http://julien.danjou.info/projects/emacs-packages#rainbow-mode). It's a minor mode that fontifies the text color descriptions as you type them.

Very user-friendly, since it's got only one interactive function (i.e. `rainbow-mode`).
It's available from MELPA.

[image: rainbow-mode example]

Comment: Also directly available from GNU ELPA.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of tools that can help:

- [`hexcolour.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HexColour) -- shows such hex color codes in their own color in the text
- [`palette.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorPalette) -- interactive color palette: takes such hex codes as input and provides them as output (in addition to color names etc.)
- [`hexrgb.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/hexrgb.el) -- (used by the color palette and other libraries) color manipulation functions

The first one, `hexcolour.el`, is the closest to what you asked for.